# Как отправлять только алерты крона?

Tags: linux, cron

Возникла задача. Необходимо, что для всех задач в файлах крона. Была возможность отправки алертов крона на почту. Например, если скрипт запустился с ошибкой.

Comment: Крону неизвестно как именно запустился ваш скрипт =) добавляйте внешний обработчик или прямо в ваши скрипты отправку мэйла при ошибках....

Comment: Вы не поверите. Но - `man cron`, `man crontab`, и гугл...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вы не поверите - крон умеет отпрвлять почту "из коробки". Экзим ставится в зависимостях в популярных дистрах вместо sendmail - надо его только чуток поднастроить.

Comment: @eri Вы не поверите, но я не говорил что крон не умеет почту отправлять, я говорил что крон не умеет анализировать как отработал скрипт пользователя. он может либо отправлять информацию о каждом запуске, либо ни о каком.. а отправлять только ОШИБКИ он не может.

Comment: как это не умеет? exit code я  ему писал через `|| true` чтоб он меня лишним спамом не донимал))

Answer (score 1):

в cron можно указать MAILTO=user